# Blow MSP430 security fuse with FET430 or MSP-FETFlash programmer

Tags: msp430, fuses, security

Is it possible to use a FET430, MSP-FETFlash or similar programmer to program and then blow the security fuse of the MSP430 devices?

We have 500 which already been soldered on the boards and were not programmed first.

Comment: Thanks. We recently solved the problem with a back door software fix but this is good information.

Answer (score 4):

Actually **only 2 TI programmers** can blow fuses (electrical and software fuses) on the MSP430 MCU line:

**MSP-FET430UIF** (the white box, mini USB)

and

**MSP-FET** (the black box, micro USB)

[image]
As per document: [SLAU647M](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau647) from TI, page 4.
**But none of the eZ or MSP-EXP can.**

And YES, you dont need full JTAG, it's possible to flash fuse with SBW (spy by wire), but you need to add a protection resistor (to protect TCK pin from the 6V out of the TEST/VPP pin)

[image: SWD blow fuse with resistor protection]

Full detail from TI forum here:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/353234?Not-Able-to-blow-security-fuse-in-MSP430G2553

Note: pay attention to the programmer's pinout in SWD mode: it's completely different from the JTAG pinout label on the back of the product.

With the MSP-FET (the black with micro-USB one), it's used at my factory to blow fuse for small production batches on MSP430G2553 devices.

Finally, for the physical fuse burning (such as MSP430G2553) a quick and dirty hacky solution: apply 6V directly on the TEST pin and it's supposed to burn the interface with 100mA in 1ms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the MSP-FET430UIF supports blowing security fuse to protect code.

From the website

Supports JTAG Security Fuse blow to protect code

Source - http://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET430UIF

FYI you need to have a JTAG header to use the function. and you are not using the 2 wire JTAG/ Spy-bi-Wire